# Wi-Fi Hotspot on two Wireless cards gets very slow speed limited to barely 1Mb/s

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, budgie, ap-hotspot

I've got an hp laptop with two wireless cards, one integrated the other is connected on the usb port. I've tried to turn on the wifi hotspot and managed to connect to it with my smartphone. Than I did notice that the internet connection is limited to more or less 1Mb/s. Following you'll find my setup. I'm using the usd wifi to connect to the AP and the internal card as hotspot:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b35f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lshw -C Network
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Wireless interface
       product: USB2.0 WLAN Adapter
       vendor: Wireless Manufacturer
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: wlx00871a1504b5
       version: 2.00
       serial: 00:87:1a:15:04:b5
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.11 link=yes maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:9e:6b:c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:52500000-5257ffff memory:52580000-5258ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 74:46:a0:86:92:0f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:52404000-52404fff memory:52400000-52403fff

cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.13.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-026) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)) #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:13:23 UTC 2018

iwconfig
eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlx00871a1504b5  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"myAPname"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C4:A8:1D:37:BE:20   
          Bit Rate=18 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1300  Invalid misc:2086   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: the connection between the AP and the USB wifi device gets limited to 1mb too even if I dont use the Hotspot function, but it works fine when I disable the Hotspot on the other internal card

Comment: This might be happening because both WiFi networks are using the same channel - look into changing the channel, either for your Ubuntu hotspot, or the link from the AP to the machine.

Comment: i'm not sure how to check what channel is using. I've tried again and it looks like the receiver wifi adapter is getting 5Mb/s Down (normal because i'm far from the ap) and 1Mb/s Up. But the transmitter card gives me only 0,5Mb/s Down and 1Mb/s Up. Which is strange since is limitng only  the donwload stream